# npm and front-end dependencies

Tags: dependencies, npm, browserify

Let's say I make an Angular module which only has one dependency - the AngularJS framework.

Now let's say a user, who uses Browserify and has a clean project with no other front-end dependencies, wants to use my module he can install it via

```
npm install my-super-cool-angular-module --save
```

How will AngularJS be included when he does this? My thought was to include `angular` as a dependency in `my-super-cool-angular-module`'s `package.json`. But I haven't seen anyone else do this.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect use case for [peer dependencies](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/), to express which versions of Angular you are compatible with.

Comment: Ok so you are recommended to include other front-end dependencies in your `package.json`? Or is it recommended to just state which dependencies are supported, and which versions, in like your README?

Comment: Also, are you supposed to utilize the `main` property in `package.json` as you do with `bower.json`.

Comment: You should include dependencies in package.json in the dependencies property; you should include things you are compatible with in the peerDependencies property. And yes, main is important for npm. https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html